# Is it possible to add exceptions for which controller actions the default authorization policy should not be used?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authorization, policy-based-security

If we want our ASP.NET Core application to use the default authorization policy on all actions, except X actions, how would we do that, other than defining separate policies/using an Authorization Filter that will filter them based on the request's URI?

To add the default policy to all our endpoints, we can do the following in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers()
                .RequireAuthorization();
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [AllowAnonymous] above the X actions where you do not want authorization

Comment: That implies no authorization at all will be used on those X actions. I'm asking about making an **exception** to the authorizations we'll be adding, not making them void of any.